# using null-coalescing operator inside if statement (C#)

Tags: c#

I know null-coalescing operator returns the left hand operand if it is not null, but I hadn't seen anyone using it in an if-statement like:

```
if (car.IsSold ?? false)
 ...
```

I'm guessing it means if car.IsSold is not null then proceed with the if statement, otherwise jump out of the statement. Is that right? if yes, why shouldn't the programmer use

```
if (car.IsSold)
...
```

which does the exact same thing?
I'd appreciate if someone clears this up for me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250888/discussion-on-question-by-brainoverflow-using-null-coalescing-operator-inside-if).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which does the exact same thing?

No it doesn't.  Because a `bool?` (or `Nullable<bool>`) and a `bool` are not the exact same thing.

An `if` condition *must* resolve to a `bool`.  But a `bool?` *might* resolve to `null` at runtime.  So the compiler won't allow that.  You have to provide logic in the condition which will still return a `bool` in the event that the value in question is `null`.  Probably the simplest way to do that is the null-coalescing operator and a default literal.

Comment: the reason the compiler does not allow that isn't bc it might resolve to null.. it's bc that there is no implicit cast

Comment: @Adrian: Two ways of saying the same thing, really.  The compiler is attempting to interpret the condition as a `bool` because that's what it requires.  If the result is a `bool`, the necessity is met.  If it isn't, the compiler attempts to find an implicit cast from whatever the condition does resolve to.  Ultimately it needs to become a `bool`.

Comment: no, you're arguing that it won't allow that bc it might resolve to null. If you explicitly cast to bool it *still* might, but it will compile

Comment: @Adrian: Which would result in a runtime error instead of a compile time error, which the compiler is specifically meant to avoid. But still it's semantically the same thing that I've described. The explicit cast resolves to a `bool` (at least as far as the compiler is concerned, since it's really the developer telling the compiler "don't worry about this, I promise it'll be a `bool`"), which is what an `if` requires. The explicit cast may fail at runtime, but that's a different problem. We're both saying the same thing, and we're both right, we're just describing it differently to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `car.IsSold` is nullable:

```
if (car.IsSold)
```

does not even compile since `bool?` does not implicitly cast to `bool`

---

The explicit cast

```
 if ((bool)car.IsSold)
```

will throw an exception if `car.IsSold` is `null`

---

Using the null-coalescing operator

```
if (car.IsSold ?? false)
```

would work in this case, among other solutions.

Comment: Or simply use `car.IsSold.GetValueOrDefault()` which returns `false` if `IsSold` is null.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann In this case I find the null-coalescing operator way more readable, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann actually i think the ?? version is better, its less typing and the default is explicitly given

Comment: @da_berni yeah, I'd also prefer the `??` operator, I was just adding an option.